# access Class attribute my name

Tags: java, reflection

Can I access a `Class` attribute by its name?

for example:

```
class Test {
    Integer GoodVar;
    Integer BadVar;
    ...

    void Func(String name, Integer value) {
        // Set A Value based on its name
    }

    void Init() {
        Func("GoodVar", 2);
        Func("BadVar", 1);
    }
}
```

can somebody code `Func` function?

Comment: why don't you use constructor : `Test() { this.GoodVar=2; this.BadVar=1; }` ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not using getters and setters?

Comment: Yes. I have a very good reason for not using basic code. But describing it is totally out of concept here.

Comment: Try comparing the input string to what you would expect, and if the strings match, use the line above: this.GoodVar=value 
Also, you could use exceptions if the string passed doesn't match..

Comment: That's the Basic idea. But I wonder if someone can find a better solution. Using Reflections maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a switch statement, in JDK 7 the strings are allowed (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html). Something like:

```
switch (name) {
     case "GoodVar":
         GoodVar = value;
         break;
     case "BadVar":
         BadVar = value;
         break;
     default:
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name: " + name);
 }
```

Pre JDK 7 you can use if statements instead. 
Another approach it would be to use reflection (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), but it's slow, like:

```
Field f = getClass().getField(name);
if (f!=null){
 f.setAccessible(true);
 f.setInt(this, value);
}else
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name: " + name);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the Basic idea. But I wonder if someone can find a better solution. Using Reflections maybe.

Comment: @MBZ I was just updating my answer, to suggest also reflection :)

Comment: reflection make your program slow.

Comment: @Quoi I mentioned that in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called reflection. 
You can do the following:

```
void Func(String name, Integer value) {
    Field f = getClass().getField(name);
    f.setAccessible(true); // needed because f is not public
    f.setInt(this, value)
}
```

But may I add some comments?

1. fields, variables and methods by convention must start with small letter.
2. Fields must be private. There are a couple of special cases when they can be protected or package protected. This is not your case.

Comment: Thanks specially for your comments. :)

Comment: Probably you should handle the case when there is no such field too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void Func(String name, Integer value) {
    // Set A Value based on its name
    Field f = getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(this, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```
package SO;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class Test {
    Integer GoodVar;
    Integer BadVar;

    void Func(String name, Integer value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if (name.equals(field.getName())) {
        field.set(this, value);
        }
    }
    }
   // or a optimul way:
 void Func1(String name, Integer value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, SecurityException,
        NoSuchFieldException {
    Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(this, value);
    }
    void Init() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Func("GoodVar", 2);
    Func("BadVar", 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "[GoodVar->" + GoodVar + ",BadVar-> " + BadVar + "]";
    }
}
```

With sample Main method :

```
package SO;

public class TestTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Test test = new Test();
    System.out.println(test);
    test.Func("GoodVar", 1);
    test.Func("BadVar", 2);
    System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
[GoodVar->null,BadVar-> null]
[GoodVar->1,BadVar-> 2]
```